# PHP regex add span to text string match

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code:

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]\./', $element['#title'])) {
  $element['#title'] = preg_replace('/^[A-Z]\./', '<span>$0</span>', $element['#title']);
}
```

This will add a span tag to e.g.

```
<span>A.</span> This is a title
```

I now have several strings to match which are:

[A-Z].

[A-Z].[1-99].

[A-Z].[1-99].[1-99].

[A-Z].[1-99].[1-99].[1-99].

Regex is not my strong point! Could anyone help out please?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
^[A-Z]\.(?>[0-9]++\.?+)*
```

note that you don't need to test with preg_match before, since preg_replace make the replacement only if it finds something:

```
$element['#title'] = preg_replace('~^[A-Z]\.(?>[0-9]{1,2}\.?+)*~', '<span>$0</span>', $element['#title']);
```

Comment: Super quick response! Thanks. Weirdly that's not working? I stripped out the if statement as per you response. Have I confused things? Example string patterns would be A. or B.2 or Z.32.4

Comment: @StephenWilson: In the example strings you have given in your question, there always a dot at the end. I have edited my pattern to make it optional.

Comment: Sorry, I've messed you around again the text strings always have a dot at the end followed by some text e.g. `A.1.99. Some text here` or `B.99. More text here`

Comment: @StephenWilson: remove the end anchor `$`

Comment: Works perfectly. Wish I could get my head around regex! Thank you so much. S

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're matching a capital letter followed by a period first; then, it can be followed by zero to three occurrences of a number followed by a period:

```
/^[A-Z]\.(?:\d+\.){0,3}/
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. Casimir sorted me out but thanks for responding. S

Comment: @StephenWilson No problem; I figured this expression is less complicated to understand :)